# Why Angular 6 doesn't send HTTP Get/Post requests?

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, angular6

I have the following Service in Angular 6:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(): Observable<boolean> {
        var url = `${environment.baseAPIUrl}${environment.loginUrl}`;

        return this.http.get<boolean>(url);
    }
}
```

I call it from my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bpms-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    login() {
        var self = this;
        self.loginService.login();
    }
}
```

Why it doesn't send my request?

[image: Developer Network]

Comment: You've to Subscribe the [`Observable `](https://angular.io/guide/observables) .. It should have been         `self.loginService.login().subscribe()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Observable` doesn't get called until you subscribe to it. `Http` API method return `Observable`, just by calling observable won't make and API call.

```
self.loginService.login().subscribe(
  (data) => console.log('Logged in successfully')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Http Calls are not made until it is being **subscribed** to returned observable.

```
@Component({
selector: 'bpms-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

login() {
    var self = this;
    self.loginService.login().subscribe();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **call** your `login()` function, for example in `ngOnInit()` or on form submit event, be sure that you call it.

and update your `login()` function, look like this code:

```
login() {
    this.loginService.login()
        .subscribe((res) => console.log('login() response!'));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your return type is Observable<> you need to subscribe to it, to get response once its ready.So your code will some thing like this

```
@Component({
selector: 'bpms-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

login() {
    var self = this;
    self.loginService.login().subscribe();
 }
}
```